# IsInRole fails after implementing OnModelCreating MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have yet another case of IsInRole failing :( I started my app by simply creating a MVC 5 project running .NET Framework 4.5 and MVC as the selected template. I created then some users, assigned roles and added the following validation to _Layout.cshtml

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Instructor"))
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Instructors", "Index", "Instructor")</li>
}
```

Everything worked fine until I needed to implement OnModelCreating because I needed a one to many relationship between users in User table. The change looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
.HasMany(p => p.RelatedUsers)
.WithMany()
.Map(m =>
{
    m.MapLeftKey("Id");
    m.MapRightKey("RelatedId");
    m.ToTable("users_related");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId }); 
}
}
```

This is were the problem started. BTW, for some reason doing this changes the table names to Identity[Name of the aspnet table], so since I didn't have any data I decided to just nuke to re-create the db from scratch and investigate how to properly scaffold it later.

The database was created, the seed method which created users, roles and assigned roles to does users ran without a problem and everything was inserted in the tables just fine but IsInRole just stopped working.

Based on the answers I found from folks in stackoverflow and other websites I've tried, without success, the following:

1. Delete cookies from browser.
2. Enable role manager in web.config. For this I created a sqlProvider pointing to my      DefaultConnection and run aspnet_regsql on the database (otherwise I'd get an error indicating that aspnet_SchemaVersions doesn't exists or I don't have permissions over it).
3. Change User.IsInRole for Roles.GetRolesForUser("user").Contains("role") and Roles.IsUserInRole().
4. Didn't have much faith in this one but hey, who knows: Rename the Identity tables to AspNet by doing: modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("AspNetUsers") to all identity tables on OnModelCreating
5. Validate that the user was actually authenticated and repeat the 1,2,3 and 4.

The only thing I can do to get it running again is deleting OnModelCreating method.This completely restores IsInRole functionality (just for the record, Roles.GetRolesForUser("user").Contains("role") never returned true regardless of the presence of OnModelCreating, Roles.IsUserInRole did return true though.)

Please help! I go to bed and wake up thinking about what's wrong with this validation. I just can't understand what is the relationship between the roles and implementing OnModelCreating.

Thanks,

Comment: I've noticed something, to get Roles.IsUserInRole to work (previously I mentioned that it does return true but this is only when OnModelCreating is not implemented) you need to add roles via Roles.CreateRole and Roles.AddUserToRole. The role and the userId-RoleId association go instead to table dbo.aspnet_Roles and dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles instead of going to IdentityRole and IdentityUserRole respectively and I was using RoleManager to add the roles. Does User.IsInRole is looking for the role in a different table?

Comment: When this line is executed `var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);` look at the identity that was created and see if it contains your roles.

Comment: Thanks Shoe, not sure where to look inside identity but didn't find anything that looked like the roles. This is what the object looks like:                                                                      userIdentity
+ Actor
 AuthenticationType
 BootstrapContext
+ Claims
 IsAuthenticated
 Label
 Name
 NameClaimType
 RoleClaimType

Comment: The roles come through the `UserManager` and get set on the identity as claims. Find the line I gave you (where your sign in logic is at) and see if the identity object has those roles.

Comment: Ok! I found the roles property, but the symptom remains the same. I do see roles with no OnModelCreating implementation, but if implemented the array containing the roles is empty!